# How to remove blank from SQLCMD output

Tags: windows, sql-server-2008, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I am running a batch file by using the below command which basically pulls the data from a sql table.My result txt file is giving a blank line at the end.

```
SQLCMD.EXE -d FCRS_STG -i D:\export.sql -o E:\result.txt -s"," -W -h-1
```

export.sql was a simple select query as

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
SELECT * from dbo.VW_FDM_SALES_ADJUST where app ='CN'
```

Please help me to remove the blank line.

Thanks,
Ravi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This removes the last line:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" result.txt') do set /a count=%%i
for /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%i in ('findstr /n "^" result.txt') do if %%i lss %count% >>newfile.txt echo.%%j
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but no luck :(

Comment: The first forloop counts the lines and the second writes all lines except the last one to `newfile.txt`. What is your output?